# Using an If statement in SVG

Tags: svg

I'm wanting to create a pattern book by using `SVG` as it seems quite a fun language and I was wondering if there's a way of using an `if statement` instead of typing all the different rectangles out one by one. The code that I have is

```html
<SVG width="1000" height="1000">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="50" y="100" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="150" y="200" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="240" y="150" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="190" y="30" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="95" y="56" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="19" y="81" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="290" y="190" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="200" y="300" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="189" y="359" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="286" y="389" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="260" y="346" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="20" y="370" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="355" y="410" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="320" y="385" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="61" y="399" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="100" y="450" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="160" y="425" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
  <rect x="300" y="400" width="150" height="150" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1"/>
</SVG>
```

As you can see, I have a fair bit of rectangles being displayed which does work, but I'm wondering if there's a way of using an `if statement` to make it easier to use.

Comment: [Scripting for SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/script.html)

Comment: How would that help you?

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I'm looking into that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is not a language.  But you can use languages to build your SVG.  For example, in an HTML page, you can build the SVG thusly:

```js
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
var num = 20;
while (num-- > 0)
{
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
  rect.setAttribute("x", Math.random()*500);
  rect.setAttribute("y", Math.random()*500);
  rect.setAttribute("width", "150");
  rect.setAttribute("height", "150");
  rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1");
  mysvg.appendChild(rect);
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="1000">
</svg>
```

You can also embed the Javascript into the SVG to make it stand-alone and not rely on HTML.

```html
<svg id="mysvg" width="1000" height="1000"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <script type="application/ecmascript"> <![CDATA[
    var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
    var num = 20;
    while (num-- > 0)
    {
      var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
      rect.setAttribute("x", Math.random()*500);
      rect.setAttribute("y", Math.random()*500);
      rect.setAttribute("width", "150");
      rect.setAttribute("height", "150");
      rect.setAttribute("style", "fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1");
      mysvg.appendChild(rect);
    }  
  ]]></script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work when I go onto the `Run code snippet` button but when I copy it into my file or create a new one, it doesn't display anything

Comment: It seems to only want to open in Internet Explorer and not any other browsers when I save it as an `.svg` file

Comment: Not sure why that is. It works fine for me if I save it and load it into Chrome or Firefox.  Are you double-clicking on the SVG? If so, it will obviously depend on which program you have .svg files associated with.

Comment: this is pretty much what I want to do except instead of Random, I want to use array values for x. setAttribute("x", myArray[num].value) - do you think that might work?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to need a loop rather than an IF, but SVG has no concept of either.

You can generate your SVG using a programming or template language.

For example, with [template toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/) (which you will need to install and run, it isn't an SVG feature):

```
[% SET data = [
    { x="10", y="10", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="50", y="100", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="150", y="200", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="240", y="150", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="190", y="30", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="95", y="56", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="19", y="81", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="290", y="190", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="200", y="300", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="189", y="359", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="286", y="389", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="260", y="346", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="20", y="370", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="355", y="410", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="320", y="385", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="61", y="399", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="100", y="450", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="160", y="425", width="150", height="150" },
    { x="300", y="400", width="150", height="150" }
]; %]

<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    [% FOR item IN data %]
        <rect x="[% item.x %]" 
              y="[% item.y %]"
              width="[% item.width %]"
              height="[% item.height %]" 
              style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;opacity:1" />
    [% END %]
</svg>
```

Comment: using CSS would save about the same amount of written chars + supported in all modern web browsers and most svg viewers